# Unable to browser solr schema. Getting the following error:

Tags: solr, solr5, fedora-commons

I tried to check solr schema from the web console, but there is error while accessing that too. From the logs:

```
INFO: 2016-04-11        06:19:16        0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 -       0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 8983    POST    /solr/schema/fields     -       500     486     558     50      http://myserver.net:8983   curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.18 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2    -
36865524 ERROR (qtp59559151-18) [   x:fedora] o.a.s.h.RequestHandlerBase java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /opt/HWEEArchive/solr/solr-5.5.0/server/solr/fedora/data/index/segments_18
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:55)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:144

36865527 INFO  (qtp59559151-18) [   x:fedora] o.a.s.c.S.Request [fedora]  webapp=/solr path=/admin/luke params={show=index&numTerms=0&wt=json&_=1460355771692} status=500 QTime=7
36865530 ERROR (qtp59559151-18) [   x:fedora] o.a.s.s.HttpSolrCall null:java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /opt/HWEEArchive/solr/solr-5.5.0/server/solr/fedora/data/index/segments_18
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:55)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:144
```

Comment: Ok, I found it. It's permission issue. I used to run solr with root and now using with solr user. I have fixed the file permissions of all the solr directories. But, don't know which particular directory contains the schema  . Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found it. It's permission issue. I used to run solr with root and now using with solr user. I have fixed the file permissions of all the solr directories. Then it started working.